# Need to extract rows with PHPexcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

Hi i would like to extract entire rows in a new sheet , a new file in .xlsx when the value of the 4th colums is "30300" but i don't know  how could i do that  ?

I'm stucked because i don't know how i could extract lines , i tried some IF in the For Each but i got few errors

```
<?php
require_once 'C:/wamp/www/Stage/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';


$objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("HES.xlsx");
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0);

echo '<table border="1">';

foreach($sheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {

    echo '<tr>';

    foreach ($row->getCellIterator() as $cell) {
        echo '<td>';
        if ($cell->getvalue() == 'MT201501')
        {
           $cell->setvalue('NewNum');
        }

        if ($cell->getvalue() == 'Haute école de santé')
        {
           $cell->setvalue('HETS');
        }


        print_r($cell->getValue());
        echo '</td>';
    }

    echo '</tr>';
}

echo '</table>';

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel);
$objWriter->save('C:/wamp/www/Stage/Try/test5.xlsx');

?>
```

I tried this to remove the row which contains "30300" in the 4th columns but not all the rows has been deleted , i don't know why not all the lines are deleted

```
    for($row=1; $row < $highestRow; ++$row){
    $value = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
 if (substr($value,0,7) == "303000") {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
      }
}
```

Comment: 'few errors'? where?

Comment: I tried some IF but this didn't worked because i don't know how to  extract theses rows  in a new file

Comment: So are you trying to create a new xls file with only those rows from "HES.xlsx" that match your  "30300" value? Or just to move them to a new worksheet in the same file?

Comment: Exactly, in a new xlsx file

Comment: Check if the row contains the value you're testing in column 4, if it doesn't then delete that row

Answer (score 0):

Try type casting the value fetched from sheet

```
for($row=1; $row < $highestRow; ++$row){
    $value = (string)$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('D'.$row)->getValue();
 if (substr($value,0,7) == "303000") {
      $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->removeRow($row);
      }
}
```

Comment: Hi i tried it, but the current problem is i have like 10-12 values for "303000" and this function only delete 8-10 values , i tried for all values and this delete only few rows not all rows. Thanks a lot for answering and for your help

Comment: Welcome friend :). Memory could be one of the issue, please make a check.